# Tag synonym request: [computer] → [computing]

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

I would like to propose synonymizing [computer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computer) (*25 questions*) with [computing](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computing) (*164 questions*).

> [computing](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computing)
>
> Questions about computers, programming and IT.

Comment: Sure, sounds obviously needed to me. But both are rare enough that I don't know of anyone who can vote on it.

Comment: @JJJ It is **not** a feature request; it's starting a discussion as to whether this suggestion is a good idea or not.

Comment: That said, with a score of +11/0 it seems a reasonable proposition. I can't see any questions which require [computer] rather than [computing].

Comment: @AndrewLeach appreciate the swift moderator action. :)